# input number validating but silently not binding

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I just encountered a weird behavior with mvc validation and binding against an `int`. I have my model as:

```
class YourModel
{
   ...

   [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid")]
   public int Area { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Area (m<sup>2</sup>)</label>
  <input asp-for="Area" class="form-control" />
  <span asp-validation-for="Area"></span>
</div>
```

with the above, the input gladly accepts input, say,`37.90` but silently put `0` (the `int` default) on form submission. The poor user wonders why it's not saving and after a couple of trials she starts to get angry with the developer (me, in this case).

What's the logic behind the `int` validation?

Comment: Can you use `[RegularExpression("([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "Must be a number")]` in addition to range validator?

Answer (score 0):

Type of input is decimal while type of Area property is int. When ModelBinder tries to convert decimal input '37.90' to int, it fails and assign 0 (default value of int) to Area property.

As per your Range validation rule any value lies between 0 and max value of int is valid that's why it satisfies validation rule (Since value of Area property is 0) and does not show any error.

You should change datatype of Area property in your model class to double and according to this adjust your Range Validator.